# Нововведения в Rails 5, касающиеся Active Record Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Совсем недавно перешел на Rails 5.0.0.1 и не совсем понимаю кое-каких вещей, связанных с ассоциациями Active Record. Либо я что-то упускаю (давно не брался за рельсы).

В 4-ой версии рельс я мог спокойно проделать следующие действия, не получив при этом ни одной ошибки.

```
rails g model Parent name:string
rails g model Child name:string parent:references
rake db:migrate
```

`rails c`

```
Parent.create name: "Papa"
p = Parent.last
Child.create name: "Son"
c = Child.last
```

После этих нехитрых действий можно было спокойно производить следующие действия:

```
p.children << c # Добавить "Son" к "Papa"
p.children # Вывести список всех дочерних записей
c.parent # Посмотреть родителя c
c.parent = p # Напрямую установить родителя для c
```

Это все было довольно очевидно и удобно.

Но сейчас я обновился до 5-ой версии рельс и не совсем понимаю, что происходит.

Сначала я произвел стандартные операции:

```
rails g model Parent name:string
rails g model Child name:string parent:references
rails db:migrate
```

Ничего нового.

`rails c`

```
Parent.create name: "Papa"
p = Parent.last
Child.create name: "Son" # *
```

И в строке (*) я натыкаюсь на *нечто*. Что именно - точно сказать не могу. Конкретно происходит следующее:

> (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>
> (0.1ms)  rollback transaction

Судя по всему дело в том, что я не указал, к какому родителю относится потомок, потому как если сделать что-то типа

```
p.children.create name: "Son"
```

То тогда я уже никаких роллбэков не получаю и транзакция выполняется.

Собственно, вопрос: я что-то упускаю/делаю неправильно, или действительно больше нельзя создавать модель, которая является наследником другой модели, не указывая при этом родителя? И если это так, то есть ли какой-то способ вернуть прежнее поведение? Ведь может быть такая ситуация, что есть много дочерних моделей и много родителей, но не все дочерние используются. Как тогда их создавать?

Comment: Разумеется, речь в вопросе касается ассоциации has_many - belongs_to, как с остальными - не проверял, но, уверен, ситуация та же.

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался: `Child.create(name: "Son").errors.messages` => `{:parent=>["must exist"]}`

Comment: @D-side да я что-то о bang-методах забыл. На фронтенд просто на время переключался. Мечусь меж двух огней, постоянно что-то из головы вылетает :D

Comment: Во, вы ещё один способ узнать о проблеме нашли. Можете же, когда хотите :)

Comment: @D-side все равно обычно проще консультацию у профессионала типа вас получить. Ну а так да, само собой сразу сам ищу решение.

Comment: @D-side а вот кстати еще вопрос появился. Опциональность связи нужно указывать только в строке с belongs_to или с has_many тоже? В плане `has_many :children, optional: true`. Или так не нужно делать?

Comment: А можно стать профессионалом самому, и тогда проще станет всё :) Что касается `has_many`, то [в документации такого атрибута там просто нет](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

Comment: @D-side Доходчиво, благодарю. А для того, чтобы стать профессионалом нужны годы. Я думаю, у вас не один год ушел на это.

Comment: Полтора. [Заглядывайте в чатик по теме](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41316/ruby-on-rails--), если интересно поболтать по этому поводу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, запустите последнюю команду с bang-методом `create!` вместо `create` - тогда в консоли увидите причину невыполнения операции:

```
p.children.create! name: "Son"
```

Во-вторых, вы верно предположили - в консоли вы увидите объяснение, что у объекта модели `Child` не указан обязательный параметр `parent`. Почему обязательный? Потому что в Rails 5 все связи `belongs_to` стали обязательными по-умолчанию.

В четвертых рельсах:

```
belongs_to :parent                  # по-умолчанию необязательная связь
belongs_to :parent, required: true  # уточняем обязательность связи
```

В пятых рельсах:

```
belongs_to :parent                  # по-умолчанию обязательная связь
belongs_to :parent, optional: true  # уточняем необязательность связи
```

Comment: Значит не зря я грешил на нововведения в самих рельсах :) Что ж, спасибо! Кстати, раз уж тут речь о нововведениях зашла, не подскажете, где можно откопать инфу обо всем новом, что добавили (удалили) в пятых рельсах?

Comment: http://blog.bigbinary.com/categories/Rails-5

Comment: Благодарю, надо будет ознакомиться. Спасибо еще раз за объяснение.